# Ionic web service run every time the page is opened

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am use Ionic v1 and have a problem. There are many headlines on this error. But I can't find solution for me.

I do,

```
<ion-nav-view name="other" cache-view="false"></ion-nav-view>
```

and

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    cache: false,
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
})
```

Run controller every time the page is opened. But my web service code only run when first opened

My Code:

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $ionicPopup) {

    $scope.loadingShow();

    console.log("Test"); //Run everytime but $http run only first opened

    $http.get($scope.webServiceUrl + "json_getSharedPicture.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.loadingHide();
            $rootScope.playlists = response.data;
        });

})
```

My Ionic Info:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0

local packages:

    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.2.1
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1  : 1.2.0
    Cordova Platforms         : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework           : ionic1 1.3.3

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to hit your code every time you load that page.
```

> you need to initialize a function and call it

```
function onLoad() {
$http.get($scope.webServiceUrl + "json_getSharedPicture.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.loadingHide();
        $rootScope.playlists = response.data;
    });
}onLoad();
```